# combobox dependent on another combobox - JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, combobox

I have three combo box: Country, state and city

How can I become a dependent on another? For example, if I select Brazil appears their states and later the cities of selected state. But if I select United States in the country will show their states

I am using MySQL as the database, if you need some configuration in the database also tell me ... It's the first time you work with it, thank you very much.

Comment: Obs: example of how I'm populating a combobox
public void country() {
        listCountry = countryDAO.show();
        observableListCountry = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listCountry);
        cbxCountry.setItems(observableList);
    }

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments: [edit] your question and add it there.

Answer (score 7):

Register a listener with the country combo box and update the state combo box when the selected item changes:

```
cbxCountry.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == null) {
        cbxState.getItems().clear();
        cbxState.setDisable(true);
    } else {
        // sample code, adapt as needed:
        List<State> states = stateDAO.getStatesForCountry(newValue);
        cbxState.getItems().setAll(states);
        cbxState.setDisable(false);
    }
});
```

You could also do this with bindings if you prefer:

```
cbxState.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    Country country = cbxCountry.getValue();
    if (country == null) {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    } else {
        List<State> states = stateDAO.getStatesForCountry(country);
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(states);
    }
},
cbxCountry.valueProperty());
```

(and if you want the disable functionality from the solution above also do `cbxState.disableProperty().bind(cbxCountry.valueProperty().isNull());`).